# Create buckets to locate months in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column in excel named  Month which consists data like-

When you create a chart with E_no by month you will get something like this
**This is what the column exactly means**
(In Jan 765 people were hired
In jan-feb-Mar 2276 people were hired)

How the chart looks like

Jan.  -----------765

Jan-feb-mar  ---------------------- 2276

Sep-Oct. ---------- 10

Oct. -------- 2

(the dashes are basically the bars of a horizontal bar graph and Jan, jan-feb-Mar as my Y axis)

| E no | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2038 | feb-mar-jun |
| 657 | Sep-Oct |
| 221 | Jun |
| 6507 | Oct |
| 876 | Mar-Apr-May |
| 17 | Nov-Dec |
| 615 | Dec |

Now what I want is to create buckets like June should fall under the category of feb-mar-jun , Dec should fall under the category of Nov-dec, Oct should fall under the category of sep-oct.

for eg -
From these

Jan.  -----------765

Jan-feb-mar  ---------------------- 2276

Sep-oct. ---------10

Oct ----2

My o/p should look like

Jan-feb-mar  -------------------------------- 3041

Sep-Oct ------------- 12

I'm new to power bi so if anyone have any good method other than this what I  have mention would really help me to to get rid of this.
Let me know if you have any doubt regarding my question
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can create a lookup table, i.e if all the months in one column and what bucket they fall along in the next, then create a relationship between the two tables and create a simple chart which is just a groupby, what does your actual raw data look like? another method would be to hold the above logic in a switch statement or an equivilent in DAX.

Comment: The way I have shown on my table the data looks same, actually there are two dept say A & B, A hires every.month and B hires in alternate months or after 2-3 months like that.

Comment: Do u have any small  code so that I can create a new column which will give me the buckets

Comment: you first need to clean your data up, I would suggest you should split by `-` and then standardise your month names

Comment: Can you help me doing this, please write the code if u can in dax.

Comment: This is a strange dataset. What bucket does `mar` go in if you have both `feb-mar-jun` and `Mar-Apr-May`?

Comment: @Alexis Olson That's also correct but I have my data in this structure only, do you have any better approach to perform this. You can suggest if you have any good suggestion. I am new to powerbI, so don't have any idea about how a good visualisation should be performed with un arranged data